# How do I reduce treble from an electric guitar without the use of an equalizer ?

Tags: guitar

How do I reduce treble from an electric guitar without the use of an equalizer?  My patches sound very sharp. I edited them and deliberately increased "low" and reduced "high". Unfortunately, the sustain was also reduced. So, is there any other way to reduce treble ?

Comment: Need more info. What device are you using for guitar effects?

Comment: I am using a vox stomplab 2g with a 15 watts amplifier .

Comment: So I'm guessing that you have a small driver (speaker) in the amp which would tend to favor treble.  What do your patches sound like through headphones from the stomplab?

Comment: They sound warm . I guess it is the amp that is causing this.

Comment: What about tone controls on your amp?

Comment: It has bass and treble to set . But none of them work properly .

Comment: Time to get a new amp.

Answer (score 3):

Well there's the tone control on your guitar, or if you're using an amp there's the tone control on that too ..

however it's odd that the sustain was reduced when you increased the low and reduced the high in the patches. A compressor in the patch might help here.

In fact it's odd that all the patches come out trebly - does that hint that there's something odd about the device you're using to listen to your guitar?  Maybe that's at fault rather than the patches ?

Comment: Should i use compression with these settings or let compressor be the only effect ?

Comment: A compressor "Squashes"the sound, making quieter bits louder and trims down the louder parts - the overall effect on a guitar is that when you pluck a note, it allows the note to start, but smooths the attack a little, then as the note dies out it brings the volume up. Too much ofthis effect can kill the feel of what oyu're playing, but a little bit helps with sustain. It doens't affect the tone (treble/bass) too much so if it's still too trebly, try increasing the low end and add a bit of compression - it should help.